# Problems with Parallax in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, parallax

I wrote a code in JavaScript inside bootstrap and it works. The problem is that the space bar on the right side does not stop at the end of the web page and the image does not adapt to the screen of the cell phone. Here is a snippet of my code:

```js
var perrito = document.getElementById('texty');
var one = document.getElementById('one');
var two = document.getElementById('two');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    var value = window.scrollY;

    perrito.style.marginTop = value * 2.5 + 'px';
})
```

```css
.parallaxh {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;   
  }

#texty {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }

.parallaxh img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 700px;
   pointer-events: none;
    }

.sec {
   position: relative; 
   background-color: aquamarine;
   padding: 100px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="parallaxh">    
    <img src="Images\Servicios_n\servicios1.png" id="one" alt="">  
    <h2 id="texty">Servicios</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sec">
 <h2>holitas</h2>
 <p>Culpa consequat dolor irure excepteur adipisicing incididunt cillum velit veniam nisi nulla velit ex       laborum. Sunt incididunt consequat enim proident voluptate nostrud labore qui nostrud sunt. Ipsum sit amet commodo dolore.

Elit voluptate minim consequat tempor consequat dolor dolore ut sit mollit enim. Adipisicing amet ad minim et cillum aute laboris labore duis pariatur incididunt. In sunt laborum voluptate veniam adipisicing exercitation non commodo occaecat cupidatat irure pariatur. Ut laborum ullamco exercitation magna ex est aliquip dolor ex qui aliquip veniam.

Aliquip laborum ad magna non enim laboris commodo sint occaecat magna consequat. Sunt aute mollit consequat ut sunt voluptate aliquip aliquip non nisi fugiat dolore mollit cupidatat. Quis ex quis do elit.
 </p>
</div>
```